# Solve lack of SEO in Silverlight with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, seo

Can we combine Silver-light with Asp.net to implement SEO? I mean i want to Program with ASP.net and if i need Animation i use Silver-light? Because i think it can help to find site with Search Engin, is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of silverlight applications.

1) Full blown silverlight application - The entire UI is written with silverlight.

2) Island of Richness application - In this scenario Silverlight is used to enhance a specific part of an application with Rich UI. Commone scenarios include video players, data grids, or more complex animations.

So to answer your question yes this is completely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is not search engine friendly regardless if you use ASP.NET or not. Search engines can not read the information in Silverlight so it essentially doesn't exist as far as the search engines are concerned. If you want the information displayed by Silverlight to be found and indexed by the search engines you will need to provide an alternative means of displaying that content. This is usually done by placing HTML within the `<object>` tag used to display Silverlight content. It is only shown when Silverlight is not available in a browser and search engines can see it just fine. (It's basic accessibility).

Answer (score 0):

SEO *of* Silverlight sites is certainly doable (ignore anyone that still says it is not),

### SEO *on* a Silverlight website

- First ensure that you provide a sitemap for the searchengines. That should map to all content pages.
- Provide a parallel ASP.Net website to publish your content for the search engines to read. This is now quite easy with RIA services as an ASP.Net website can consume a RIA service just like any other WCF service.
- Make good use of headers, meta tags, titles, human-readable urls to include relevant keywords